# Boundary Conditions of a Stepped Beam

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, vibration, frequency-response

I would like to ask about the boundary conditions to be considered in a stepped beam. For a cantilever beam wherein the one end is fixed while the other end is free to oscillate along the z-axis, we can set the deflection equation to be W(x). The boundary conditions at the fixed end are W(0)=0 and W'(0)=0 while at the free end, W''(L)=0 and W'''(L)=0.

I would just like to ask about the boundary conditions or continuity equations that will exist at x=L1, or the boundary between the thick beam and the thin beam. What underlying equations will exist here?

Thanks a lot for your information. :)

[image]

Comment: The proportion is too large to be qualified as a stepped beam. Rather, the tiny beam is nearly fixed on the massive element. Try to adjust to within 2:1 ratio.

Comment: Also, (ignoring the fact modeling the left hand part as a beam doesn't make much sense) the neutral axes of the two beams are not at the same vertical position, which complicates the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @alephzero, if we adjusted the location of the left hand part such that the neutral axes are in the same vertical position, will we be able to properly define the junction conditions?

Comment: You have the thick beam as fixed on its left face. What does that mean? Is the beam "glued" to a structural wall or something?

Comment: It can be the case. It is similar to a cantilever beam structure wherein the left portion has no deflection and slope at x=0.